# Декодировать данные

Tags: text

Привет! подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего можно декодировать текст вида

```
_0xb1d5x1
```

чтобы все было читабельно.  спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включая телепатические способности, я угадываю, что это обфусцированное имя js переменной.
Для деобфускации всего документа, воспользуйтесь **[этим инструментом](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/)**.
Затем проанализируйте код и подберите имя для подобных переменных по смыслу.
Такие имена генерируются случайно во время обфускации, поэтому декодировать здесь нечего.
Все нужно делать ручками.